# counting pasword character when repeated allowed

Tags: combinatorics

How many six character password can be made using only A, B,C,D,E,F, 1, 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6 if 
i.  No character is reused
ii. character can be repeated as long as they are not adjacent

Answer (score 3):

You have $12$ choices for the first character.

You then have $11$ choices for the second character (anything except whatever you chose for the first character).

Similarly, $11$ choices for the third character (anything except whatever you chose for the second character).

And also $11$ choices for the fourth, fifth and sixth character.

Hence, there is a total of $$12 \times 11 \times 11 \times 11 \times 11 \times 11 = 1932612$$ possible passwords.